# how to find a set amount of letters in between symbols

Tags: python

hey I was wondering if it is possible to collect a set amount of letters or words in between brackets, an example would be I want to collect the words in between the brackets :

I like food (because it tastes) good

how can I collect the word(s) or letter(s) or number(s) in between those brackets?

thank you.

Comment: Can there be more than one pair of parentheses in a string, are they always in the correct order and properly closed, can they be nested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it using `regex` in python. I took the liberty of generalizing your example!!

```
import re
re.findall("\((.*?)\)","I like food (because it tastes) good also (hello world)")
```

##### Output:

```
['because it tastes', 'hello world']
```

##### Explanation:

The regex says that whatever expressions are present inside braces pick them out for me.

1. Why did I use `\`? Because `(` and `)` are special characters in regex. So if you want to use them as ordinary braces, you need to tell that to the compiler by using `\` before the braces.
2. Why did I use `?`?

`?` is used for two purposes:

a. Whenever you want to give an option like either this could be present or not. For eg. `apples?` would match `apple` and `apples` both.

b. Whenever you want to select a minimum of something. For eg. had I not used `?` here, the output that I would have got would be something like `['because it tastes) good also (hello world']`. Look closely and you will find that the max expression that lies inside two braces is the one selected.

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like:

```
x = "I like food (because it tastes) good"
print(len(x.split("(")[-1].split(")")[0]))
```

I believe there are better ways, but this works.

Comment: The OP wants the words/letters/numbers enclosed in the brackets while your code gives length instead.